# How to avoid using IF-Else and use inline if condition inside the .where() function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

```
 q = q.Where(s => 
                    !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id)
                    || (s.SecId != null)
                 );
```

but the **matchingrecords** could be null or having 0 items in it since it's a list. So, in that case it would fail in the above code. I want to check this contains only if
the matching records is not null and have some elements else not.

One way is to put `IF-Else` block and repeat the code but I want to do it inline, how ?

Comment: `q = matchingRecords?.Count() > 0 ? q.Where(s => 
                    !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id)
                    || (s.SecId != null)
                 ) : q;`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad since EF and LINQ to SQL are tagged, `?.` is not going to be supported.

Comment: @NetMage yes, but I'm not using it inside of an expression tree.

Comment: But the original poster is - `q` is a `IQueryable` that builds an `Expression` tree, hence the tags for EF and LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if input conditions are:

- `matchingRecords` is not null;
- `matchingRecords` not empty (contains elements, `.Count > 0`);
- no `if-else` usage allowed;

could it be done through `ternary`?

```
var list = matchingRecords?.Count > 0 ?
           q.Where(s => !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id) && s.SecId != null).ToList()
           : new List<Record>();
```

`matchingRecords?` checks for null and `.Count` after checks for "not empty". `If-else` replaced with ternary, which would filter collection using `Where` or return `new List<Record>` on `else` case.

Sample:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<int> matchingRecords; // It is null, we "forget" to initialize it

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Record>() 
        {
            new Record { Id = 0, SecId ="Some SeqId" },
            new Record { Id = 1, SecId = null },
            new Record { Id = 2, SecId = "Another SeqId" },
        };

        var filteredRecords = FilterRecords(list);
    }

    static IEnumerable<Record> FilterRecords(IEnumerable<Record> q)
    {
        return matchingRecords?.Count > 0 ? // Checking for not null and not empty (if case)
               q.Where(s => !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id) && s.SecId != null)
               : q; // else case
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SecId { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure that properly reproduced your situation, so correct me if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 q = q.Where(s => (matchingRecords != null && matchingRecords.Count > 0 && 
                !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id))
                || (s.SecId != null)
             );
```

> The condition matchingRecords != null && matchingRecords.Count > 0 will ensure !matchingRecords.Contains(s.Id) is executed only if matchingRecords has at least 1 record